# My c++ array value don't want to change, it output infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Normally, if line[num] is '>', it must add 1 to num to pass to the next character of the array and must output the corresponding character, but instead it infinitely output the sign '>'. Why?

```
//part of the code
line[] = {'>', '>', '#'};
circuit = line[num];
    while(true)
    {
        if(circuit == '>')
        {
            num++; //add 1 to num
            cout << circuit;

        } else if(circuit == '<')
        {
            num--; //substract 1 to num
            cout << circuit;

        } else if(circuit == '#')
        {
            break;
        }
```

also num is 0.

Comment: You are missing parts of the code. Also, have you stepped through this in your debugger to see what is happening for yourself?

Comment: Put `circuit = line[num]` in the while loop

Comment: `circuit = line[num];` is a one time assignment. It does *not* establish a *relationship* between `circuit` and `line[num]`. So when you update `line` or `num` later, that does *not* change `circuit`.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `circuit = line[num];` and then update num but you don't change the value of circuit which is already defined. In your if statements you can do `circuit = line[num++];`, do

```
num++;
circuit = curcuit[num]
```

Or keep what you have and put curcuit = curcuit[num] at the very top of your while loop before any of the conditionals are met.

`

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you never update `circuit`. So it will forever loop with the same character and execute the same if-branch !

It’s not either clear if `num` is initialized somewhere. Furthermore, it’s not clear how you’ll find the end of your array.

So better make line a `string` and consider a loop like:

```
for (int i=0; num<line.size(); i++) {
    circuit=line[i];
    ...
}
```

And please do not go backward in the index: so i for exploring the chars and num for the sum